# How can I rebind next-history and previous-history in Bash?

Tags: bash

I've set Bash to use vi keybindings with `set -o vi`, but I'd like to keep the Emacs-style <kbd>Ctrl-p</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-n</kbd> bindings for cycling through history. I've read the "bind" section in bash(1) and tried variations of the following:

```
bind -m vi-insert "\C-p": previous-history
bind -m vi-insert "\C-n": next-history
```

It seems that none of the `bind` commands I issue have any effect, though. The output of `bind -P` is always unchanged afterwards. How can I change the keybindings for these commands?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `help bind`:

> ```
> The non-option argument syntax is equivalent to
> that found in ~/.inputrc, but must be passed as a single argument:
> e.g., bind '"\C-x\C-r": re-read-init-file'.
> ```

I used `set -o emacs` and `bind -p | grep history` to find the arguments necessary.

The commands you need are:

```
bind '"\C-p": previous-history'
bind '"\C-n": next-history'
```

I tested this after `set -o vi` to verify they are the correct commands.

---

Also note that `help` is what you use to learn about shell builtins.  `help` itself is a shell builtin, as is `type` and `bind`.

Comment: Thanks! I read the documentation, but my eyes passed right over the part about the binding needing to be a single arguments. Enclosing it in quotes fixes the problem. The `-m` option can be followed by a binding, though; the examples I provided work fine when the binding portion is quoted.

Comment: @Ben is correct.  `help bind` is slightly misleading in the argument list.  If you search for the argument order of bind in the full `man bash` you see that `-m` is compatible with other args.

Comment: @grochmal, Ben, thanks for the correction on that point; good to know!